# Error DOMException saying Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node' while trying to replace all span by input-field in foreach

Tags: javascript, replace, stimulusjs

Like saying, i'm trying to replace all span by input-field in javascript on a foreach.
Here's my code :

```
 test({params:{idtarif}}){
   
    let tarifAModifier = document.getElementById('tarif-'+idtarif)
    let listeSpans = Array.from(tarifAModifier.getElementsByTagName("span"))

    listeSpans.forEach(element => {
        let classEl = element.classList.value
        if(classEl){
            let contenuEl = element.textContent
            let inputToDisplay = document.createElement('input')
            inputToDisplay.type = 'text'
            inputToDisplay.maxLength = 50
            inputToDisplay.setAttribute('value', contenuEl)
            inputToDisplay.classList.add(classEl)

            tarifAModifier.replaceChild(inputToDisplay, element)
        }

    });

}
```

Error is always :

```
Error invoking action "click->tarifs-administration#test"

DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node.
    at https://127.0.0.1:8000/build/app.js:1810:37
```

Do someone have an idea ?

Comment: `element` is not a child of `tarifAModifier `

Comment: Yes, but element is generate by the foreach on listeSpans, which is generate by an array.from on tarifAModifier , so i don't understand why it's not..

Comment: You didn't show your html so I don't know either